# How to combine PCA with SOM in order to get proper cluster of data points in python?

Tags: python, pca, anomaly-detection, self-organizing-maps

I have around 5 different cases where I extract around 13/14 statistical features from each case. I wanted to create like anomaly detection where I reduce the feature matrix using Principal Component Analysis (PCA) and I thought of using Self-Organising Map (SOM) in order to help organize clusters so that it becomes much clearer and then I thought of Implementing using the following to be able to do anomaly detection (I got it from this link: [Machine learning for anomaly detection and condition monitoring](https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-for-anomaly-detection-and-condition-monitoring-d4614e7de770)):

- The Mahalanobis distance metric
- Autoencoder model

The following questions are:

- Is my approach correct? (See the code below)
- How can I get the datapoints from the SOM in order to do the Mahalanobis distance metric on the new datapoints from SOM?
- How can I find the right parameters to use in SOM?
- What to do in case that the matrix from SOM has negative values?
- Can you explain what is quantization error and the smaller it is the better? Because I keep on getting error around this range: `quantization error: 0.8791745577185559`

The code:

```
def cov_matrix(data, verbose=False):
    covariance_matrix = np.cov(data, rowvar=False)
    if is_pos_def(covariance_matrix):
        inv_covariance_matrix = np.linalg.inv(covariance_matrix)
        if is_pos_def(inv_covariance_matrix):
            return covariance_matrix, inv_covariance_matrix
        else:
            print("Error: Inverse of Covariance Matrix is not positive definite!")
    else:
        print("Error: Covariance Matrix is not positive definite!")

def MahalanobisDist(inv_cov_matrix, mean_distr, data, verbose=False):
    inv_covariance_matrix = inv_cov_matrix
    vars_mean = mean_distr
    diff = data - vars_mean
    md = []
    for i in range(len(diff)):
        md.append(np.sqrt(diff[i].dot(inv_covariance_matrix).dot(diff[i])))
    return md

def MD_detectOutliers(dist, extreme=False, verbose=False):
    k = 3. if extreme else 2.
    threshold = np.mean(dist) * k
    outliers = []
    for i in range(len(dist)):
        if dist[i] >= threshold:
            outliers.append(i)  # index of the outlier
    return np.array(outliers)

def MD_threshold(dist, extreme=False, verbose=False):
    k = 3. if extreme else 2.
    threshold = np.mean(dist) * k
    return threshold

def is_pos_def(A):
    if np.allclose(A, A.T):
        try:
            np.linalg.cholesky(A)
            return True
        except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
            return False
    else:
        return False

## Get the Statistical features
## Form matrix
## Obtain the principal components
## Do SOM to the principal components (I am using miniSOM)
    # Initialization of SOM and training:
    som_shape = (1, 5)
    full_PCA_dataframe_np = full_pca_dataframe.to_numpy()
    som = MiniSom(som_shape[0], som_shape[1], full_PCA_dataframe_np.shape[1], sigma=.4, learning_rate=.15, neighborhood_function='gaussian')
    som.train_batch(full_PCA_dataframe_np, 8000, verbose=True)

    # each neuron represents a cluster
    winner_coordinates = np.array([som.winner(x) for x in full_PCA_dataframe_np]).T
    # with np.ravel_multi_index we convert the bidimensional coordinates to a monodimensional index
    cluster_index = np.ravel_multi_index(winner_coordinates, som_shape)
    
    # plotting the clusters using the first 2 dimentions of the data
    for c in np.unique(cluster_index):
        plt.scatter(full_PCA_dataframe_np[cluster_index == c, 0], full_PCA_dataframe_np[cluster_index == c, 1], label='cluster='+str(c), alpha=.5)

    # plotting centroids
    for centroid in som.get_weights():
        plt.scatter(centroid[:, 0], centroid[:, 1], marker='x',  s=25, linewidths=5, color='k', label='centroid')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

## Get the datapoints and Implement the Mahalanobis distance metric on each case:
data_train = np.array(X_train_PCA.values) # Say Case 1
data_test = np.array(X_test_PCA.values) # Say Case 3

# Obtain the covaraince matrix and implement Mahalanobis distance:
cov_matrix, inv_cov_matrix  = cov_matrix(data_train)
mean_distr = data_train.mean(axis=0)
dist_test = MahalanobisDist(inv_cov_matrix, mean_distr, data_test, verbose=False)
dist_train = MahalanobisDist(inv_cov_matrix, mean_distr, data_train, verbose=False)
threshold = MD_threshold(dist_train, extreme = True)

# Form matrix with anomaly column:
anomaly_train = pd.DataFrame()
anomaly_train['Mob dist']= dist_train
anomaly_train['Thresh'] = threshold
# If Mob dist above threshold: Flag as anomaly
anomaly_train['Anomaly'] = anomaly_train['Mob dist'] > anomaly_train['Thresh']
anomaly_train.index = X_train_PCA.index
anomaly = pd.DataFrame()
anomaly['Mob dist']= dist_test
anomaly['Thresh'] = threshold
# If Mob dist above threshold: Flag as anomaly
anomaly['Anomaly'] = anomaly['Mob dist'] > anomaly['Thresh']
anomaly.index = X_test_PCA.index
anomaly.head()
```

Another question with regards to SOM, my input to SOM using PCA is 50 rows and 2 columns where I have 5 clusters. What do I need to input when it comes to SOM?
Here is my code using `miniSOM`:

```
# Initialization of SOM and training:
som_shape = (7, 7)
full_PCA_dataframe_np = full_pca_dataframe.to_numpy()
som = MiniSom(som_shape[0], som_shape[1], full_PCA_dataframe_np.shape[1], sigma=.5, learning_rate=.5, neighborhood_function='gaussian')
som.train_batch(full_PCA_dataframe_np, 8000, verbose=True)
```

Comment: With a feature length of 14 I don't believe it makes sense to combine PCA with SOM. You should learn the SOM on the feature vectors directly instead. You can use SOM coordinates as input to the distance function. For right parameters you need to work empirically. Quantization error needs to be regarded relative to your data range, the absolute number by itself doesn't tell anything. Quantization error typically is used to describe the difference between each input point and the associated model vector learned by the SOM. A lower quantization error means the SOM better fits your data.

Comment: @ypnos Thank you for your response, I am still working on it but I might ignore PCA and use SOM directly. Question here, how can I obtain the SOM coordinates? If I am using miniSOM

Comment: @ypnos Say if I am using PCA as input to SOM, will it be better to normalize the PCA dataframe before inputting it to SOM or use it as it is?

Comment: @ypnos Can you see edited question

Comment: I'm not going to further comment on a combination of PCA and SOM. I don't know anything about that "minisom" you are talking about so I am not commenting on that either.